# Angular 6 - Expected validator to return Promise or Observable in async validator

Tags: angular, angular6

In my Angular 6 app I have async validator for checking if typed email is already registered but right now I'm getting 'Expected validator to return Promise or Observable' and I don't really know why.

```
import { UserService } from '../user/service/user.service';
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, AsyncValidator } from '@angular/forms';
import * as validationUtils from '../validation/validation-utils';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmailExistValidator implements AsyncValidator {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }

  validate(emailControl: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    const email = emailControl.value;

    if (new RegExp(validationUtils.emailRegex).test(email)) {
      this.userService
      .checkIfEmailExist(email)
      .pipe(
        map(
        (data) => {
          return {emailExist: true};
        },
        (error) => {
          return null;
        }
      ));
    }
      return of(null);
  }
}
```

register-component.ts

```
  createForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['',
      [Validators.required, Validators.email],
      [EmailExistValidator.bind(this)]],
      username: ['', [Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(validationUtils.usernameRegex)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(validationUtils.passwordRegex)]],
      repeatPassword: ['', [Validators.required]]
  }, {
    validator: EqualPasswordValidator.validate
  });
  }
```

**Edit 17.08.2018**
As @Paulie suggested I changed validator declaration in formbuilder from *.bind* to pointing to *validate* function and with some tweaks to his proposition now everything works!

Final code:

register-component.ts

```
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private userService: UserService,
    private emailExistsValidator: EmailExistsValidator,
    private usernameExistsValidator: UsernameExistsValidator) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.createForm();
  }

  createForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['',
      [Validators.required, Validators.email],
      [this.emailExistsValidator.validate]],
      username: ['', [Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(validationUtils.usernameRegex)],
        [this.usernameExistsValidator.validate]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(validationUtils.passwordRegex)]],
      repeatPassword: ['', [Validators.required]]
  }, {
    validator: EqualPasswordValidator.validate
  });
  }
```

email-exists-validator.ts

```
import { UserService } from '../user/service/user.service';
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, AsyncValidator } from '@angular/forms';
import * as validationUtils from './validation-utils';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmailExistsValidator implements AsyncValidator {
    static userService: UserService;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    EmailExistsValidator.userService = userService;
  }

  validate(emailControl: AbstractControl): Promise<{ [key: string]: any } | null>
  | Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null>  {

    const email = emailControl.value;

    if (new RegExp(validationUtils.emailRegex).test(email)) {
        return EmailExistsValidator.userService
        .checkIfEmailExist(email)
        .pipe(
          map(data => ({emailExist: true})),
          catchError(error => of(null))
        );
      }

      return of(null);

}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RxJS's map don't take a second function argument. 
I guess you want something like this:

```
if (new RegExp(validationUtils.emailRegex).test(email)) {
  return this.userService
  .checkIfEmailExist(email)
  .pipe(
    map(data => {emailExist: true}),
    catchError(error => null)
  );
}

return of(null);
```

Comment: Are there any console errors? `.bind(this)` may mess up with the `userService` injector. Try to remove it.

Comment: Yeah you was right. Bind was causing errors in this case. I edited my question with final working version.

Comment: +1 for the return of(null). Still have to understand exactly what it does, but it fixed the error for me. I was returning just null.

Comment: `of(null);` creates the RxJS Subject (object you can `.subscribe()`) which always 'sends' `null` (or other value/value sequence in you specify in the parameter) to the Subscriber.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html

Answer (score 9):

When you add multiple validators, then you need to add your validators inside another third bracket '[]' . Like Below:

```
this.yourForm= this.formBuilder.group({
    amount: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the observable from `checkIfEmailExist`:

```
// ...
return this.userService
  .checkIfEmailExist(email)
  .pipe(
// ...
```