# Angular Custom Validator Error (Expected validator to return Promise or Observable)

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I wrote a custom validator for the phone field and getting 

**error**

> Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.

for simplicity I just need to make check if the phone number i less than 10 characters

**html**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3"
                                       [ngClass]="{
                                     'has-error':(ersaForm.get('phone').touched || ersaForm.get('phone').dirty ) &&
                                     !ersaForm.get('phone').valid
                                     }">

                                    <label for="phoneId" class="control-label">Phone</label><br />
                                    <p-inputMask mask="(999) 999-9999" formControlName="phone"  inputStyleClass="form-control" [style]="{'width': '100%','height':'34px'}"  id="phoneId"  placeholder="Phone (required)"></p-inputMask>
                                    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(ersaForm.get('phone').touched || ersaForm.get('phone').dirty ) &&
                                     ersaForm.get('phone').errors">
                                        <span *ngIf="ersaForm.get('phone').errors.phonePBXCheck">
                                            invalivd Phone Number.
                                        </span>

                                    </span>

                                </div>
```

**TS**

```
function phoneCheck(phone: string): ValidatorFn{
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {

       var phoneVal = c.value;
            phoneVal = phoneVal.replace('(', '');
            phoneVal = phoneVal.replace(')', '');
            phoneVal = phoneVal.replace('-', '');
            phoneVal = phoneVal.replace('_', '');
            phoneVal = phoneVal.replace(' ', '');
            console.log('custom validation ' + phoneVal);
            if (c.value != undefined && isNaN(c.value) ||  phoneVal.lenght<10) {
                return { 'phonePBXCheck': true };
        };
        return null;
    };
}

     this.ersaForm = this._fb.group({
            phone: ['', Validators.required, phoneCheck('')],
        });
```

What AM I Missing?

Comment: Are you using Angular 6? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864074/angular-6-expected-validator-to-return-promise-or-observable-in-async-validato/51873436) SO question.

Comment: i am using angular 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: You just need to wrap your validators in an Array.

```
 this.ersaForm = this._fb.group({
   phone: ['', [Validators.required, phoneCheck('')]],
 });
```

Also, for just as a suggestion you can remove these lines from your validator:

```
phoneVal = phoneVal.replace('(', '');
phoneVal = phoneVal.replace(')', '');
phoneVal = phoneVal.replace('-', '');
phoneVal = phoneVal.replace('_', '');
phoneVal = phoneVal.replace(' ', '');
```

and instead use the `unmask` attribute of `p-inputMask` to keep your model value clean:

```
 <p-inputMask mask="(999) 999-9999" formControlName="phone" 
   inputStyleClass="form-control"
   [unmask]="true"
   [style]="{'width': '100%','height':'34px'}" id="phoneId"
   placeholder="Phone (required)">
 </p-inputMask>
```

**Update**: After playing around a bit more I noticed that `p-inputMask` does not support other validators, it only provides the `required` attribute for you, even if your custom validator is called, the control itself will remain valid.

Comment: this does not work for me...first validator must accept a parameter, second i cant change from (  this.ersaForm = this._fb.group({
            phone: ['', Validators.required, phoneCheck('')],
        });) to this.ersaForm = new FormGroup({
    'phone': new FormControl(this.phone, [Validators.required, phoneValidator]),
 });) As i have many many contrls not just the phone

Comment: @rgoal.. Updated answer